# login issue in magento

Tags: login

When some person try to login with username and password already created or try to reset password magento says this mail id is not registed in the database even if person buy some product and come back again even then it shows email id is not registed. How to rectify this problem.

I think this is cookies issue but don't know how to resolve this issue can any person help me in this problem...

Answer (score 1):

You can test also this answer:

[Admin login looping around](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31963/admin-login-looping-around/31993#31993)

Sometimes the validation cookie in Google Chrome not works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because in the login.phtml key is not included
so to resolved this problem you have to add key in to app>design>frontend>default>theme>template>customer>form>login.phtml

```
<ul class="form-list">
```

And add following code into this file

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

and also in persistent
app>design>frontend>default>theme>template>persistent>customer>form>login.phtml

Thank You

Comment: thank you Hiral but my issue is resolved for now.... i really appreciate your effort....thank you 1ce again...

Comment: okay...good luck..!!

Comment: Hi, please mark the answer that solved your problem as accepted or add your own and then accept it. This website is still in beta and we need an answer rate of 80%. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

There are some problem for this issue, try:

- Check key in app/etc/local.xml exist or not.
- Use Firefox instead of Chrome.
- Test on local should have dot "." in domain, like localhost.com, instead of localhost/magento/

Then reset password query in mysql:

```
UPDATE `admin_user` SET `password` = MD5('admin123') WHERE `username` = 'admin';
```

Hope this help.